# How can I create a long tail chart with chart.js

Tags: charts, chart.js

I want to create a long tail chart like this:

[image: long tail chart]

I was considering using `Chart.js` - line stacked area to make the basic shape. But how can I create the areas inside with different colors? Or are there any better ways?

My purpose is to create an animated banner for a product home page.

Comment: I found that I can pass a null value to create a similar effect:

Answer (score 0):

From my experience you would have to create a plugin since Chart.js does not have to my knowledge that functionality for the line chart, i.e. you can pass multiple background colors but they seem to be ignored.

A quicker perhaps more convenient option, is to use the bar chart which does allow you to specify the background colors along with a logarithmic scale.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I can pass a null value to create a similar effect with line chart:

datasets: [{
                    label: "My First dataset",
                    backgroundColor: window.chartColors.blue,
                    borderColor: window.chartColors.blue,
                    data: [
                      null,
                      2000,
                      1000,
                      800,
                      380,
                      200,
                      0,
                    ],
                    fill: true,
                }, {
                    label: "My Second dataset",
                    fill: true,
                    backgroundColor: window.chartColors.red,
                    borderColor: window.chartColors.red,
                    data: [
                      3000,
                      2000,
                      0,
                      0,
                      0,
                      0,
                      0
                    ],